# can the final keyword alone be used to define a constant in java

Tags: java, variables, static, constants, final

The java documentation mentioned that

> The static modifier, in combination with the final modifier, is also
>   used to define constants.

I was just wondering, can the final keyword alone be used to define a constant in java. I know that variable declared with final keyword and without static keyword can't be changed, but does it count as a constant?

Comment: For constants, there is no need to keep separate variable in each instance, so it is ok for it to be `static`. It's more about code style convention

Comment: In general you may use just final for method constants. The static is used but it is not must (in case of local constants)

Comment: Static and final are not sufficient for something to be a constant. Consider `static final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`. The value also has to be immutable.

Comment: Any variable declared with `final` keyword is counted as a constant. Any static method can not access to any non-static variable (or property).

Comment: please note that final variables can be initialized in constructors and static { } and { } blocks. So IMO, `public static final ...` is the best way to mark something as a constant

Comment: As Sasha told, its more about convention. Not sure but if you meant to ask that is 'final-static' combination is the only way?, then No, we also have rich 'Enums' in Java to declare constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the *static* keyword to eliminate the context of the Class instance.
Take a look at the following code:

```
public class Main {

public static final String CONST;

static {
    if((System.currentTimeMillis() % 2) == 0) {
        CONST = "FOO";
    }
    else {
        CONST = "BAR";
    }
}

public final String CONST2;

public Main(){
    if((System.currentTimeMillis() % 2) == 0) {
        CONST2 = "FOO";
    }
    else {
        CONST2 = "BAR";
    }   
}
```

}

While creating multiple instances of *Main* will result in different values for *CONST2*, *CONST* will be initialized when the class is loaded and so stays the same over several instances of *Main*.

The more interesting is that you may even have a *static final* variable with different values in case that multiple *ClassLoaders* are involved.

**So, a constant in Java is a *final static* variable that is initialized with a constant value.**

Answer (score 2):

Final variables are immutable, but static specifies that it's not an instance variable but class variable. So you can use final variable inside your class but if you need it to be used as a application-wide  constant it should be public, and you definitely don't want to create the new class instance to access your constant so it should be static.

In general you may use just final for method constants.

http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/Using-Constants.htm

Answer (score 2):

By not defining `static` you will create a copy of your constant with each new instance. I am not sure if constant must be unique by definition, but do not think, that you want multiple copies of the same constant.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a variable as `final` you can assign a value to it only once.

A non static final variable can only be declared inside a scope, e.g. in a method like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final int maxValue = 4711;
  // ...
}
```

Inside this method you cannot change the value of `maxValue`. So it is a constant but only visible inside the scope of this method.

You can also declare a class attribute as final:

```
public class MyClass {
  final String name;

  public MyClass() {
    name = "Big Jim";
  }
  // ...
}
```

So after assigning a value to the final attribute you cannot change it anymore.

Apparently it is not possible to access these variables from static methods.

So most often we use `final` together with `static` for constants, because these are not bound to specific instances.

Beware that the final keyword only protects you from assigning new values to the variable. If the type is a mutable class you can still change the inner state of the instance.